# limit run On User interface Thread to just one fragment

Tags: android, multithreading

i have a fragment class that i need to refresh a list view in it and i use a Thread but my problem here is that it runs it on other fragments too i mean when i scroll to other fragments it runs this Thread to refresh the list view but there is no list view there so i get a force close!!

here is my code:

```
Thread thread = new Thread()
{
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while(true) {
                Thread.sleep(2000);

                getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {  
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        refreshlist(view);
                    }
                });
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};

thread.start()
```

So any Help!!
Thanks in advance!

Update:

```
import java.util.List;

import mr.chag.va.lagar.R;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragment;

public class caleryhistory extends SherlockFragment {
    List<calery_lagari> Calery_lagari;
    calery_lagari_SQLiteData data;
    ArrayAdapter<calery_lagari> adapter;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.calery_history, null);
        return v;

    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(final View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        data = new calery_lagari_SQLiteData(getActivity());
        data.open();
        Calery_lagari = data.findall();
        adapter = new calery_lagari_history_adapter(getActivity(), Calery_lagari);
        final ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        listView.invalidateViews();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        Button b = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                data.db.delete(calery_lagari_SQLiteOpenHelper.TABLE_calery,
                        null, null);
                refreshlist(view);
            }
        });

        Thread thread = new Thread()
        {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    while(true) {
                        Thread.sleep(2000);

                        caleryhistory.this.getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {  
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                Calery_lagari = data.findall();
                                refreshlist(view);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };

        thread.start();
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    }

    public void refreshlist(View view) {
        Calery_lagari = data.findall();
        adapter = new calery_lagari_history_adapter(getActivity(), Calery_lagari);
        ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: The refreshList() method is inside the main activity? You should use an interface to do this job.Please post the code where the thread is included in.

Comment: Sorry but why are you using android.R.id.list?

Comment: @TheRedFox is it important? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Activity define

public static boolean check = false;

when your fragment is gone set it to `true` . Now you can check for this variable in your while loop and break the loop.

```
if(check){
break;
}
```